# "Play hothand", what does it mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

What does it mean? All Quiet On The Western Front

> “I wish I could **play hothand** with her once, my hat——” Haie beams, proud that his girl should receive so much appreciation.

Answer (score 1):

I think the translator may have made up "hot-hand". There is no trace of it on the internet, as you may have discovered. I've never heard of it.

Perhaps the reason is that what is translated as "hot-hand" is a game that the Germans call Schinkenkloppen, which may never have made it to the English-speaking countries. Check it out on German Wikipedia and run a translate into your own language. I'm glad to have learned about it.

Comment: I believe in English we call it "hot cockles" https://www.dictionary.com/browse/hot-cockles. The German Wiki entry does give an option in French as well. Having said that I had never heard of it until now.

Comment: Google Translate didn't do a good job. What does it mean? Slapping another person's bottom? How is it a game? 